# Dynamic context menu in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How do I get Dynamic context menu in jqGrid? I need to display 'menu1' for even rows and 'menu2' for odd rows? I tried to use contextmenu plugin but do not know how to implement dynamic switch between 2 context menues. Thanks.

Comment: have some code of what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you already have the contextmenu to work but need to define if the row is even or odd.

Try the following:

```
afterInsertRow: function(rowId, rowData, rowElm) {
  var trElement = $('#' + rowid);
  if(trElement.is(':even'))
    // even contextMenu
  else
    // odd contextMenu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need really bind just 'menu1' for even rows and 'menu2' for odd rows you can implement binding to grid rows inside of `loadComplete`. For example if you has

```
<div class="contextMenu" id="myMenu1" style="display:none">
    <ul style="width: 200px">
        <li id="edit1">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">Edit Row 1</span>
        </li>
        <li id="del1">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">Delete Row 1</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="contextMenu" id="myMenu2" style="display:none">
    <ul style="width: 200px">
        <li id="edit2">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">Edit Row 2</span>
        </li>
        <li id="del2">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float:left"></span>
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana">Delete Row 2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

you can make the binding so

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $("tr:even", this).contextMenu('myMenu1', {
        bindings: {
            'edit1': function(trigger) {
                alert ("Edit (menu1) id=" + trigger.id);
            },
            'del1': function(trigger) {
                alert ("Delete (menu1) id=" + trigger.id);
            }
        }
    });
    $("tr:odd", this).contextMenu('myMenu2', {
        bindings: {
            'edit2': function(trigger) {
                alert ("Edit (menu2) id=" + trigger.id);
            },
            'del2': function(trigger) {
                alert ("Delete (menu2) id=" + trigger.id);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TwoContextMenus.htm).